# Grid in xzplane

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having trouble with displaying a grid in the xzplane. I've changed the position of my z-axis like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to have a grid like in the xy-plane in my xz-plane, but since I'm rather new to gnuplot, I couldn't find the correct command.

---

My code looks like this:

```
set parametric

set xlabel "Abweichung"
set ylabel "Dosis [%]"
set zlabel "Volumen [%]"

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [0:100]
set zrange [0:100]

set xtics 0.2
set ytics 10
set ztics 10

set grid 

set border 4095 ls 1 lc rgb "black"

set xtics axis
set ytics axis
set ztics axis

set xzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
set yzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
set zzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"

set xyplane 0

splot [t=0:100] 0, t, t
```

Comment: hm...I'd like to have the same exact grid as can be seen in the lower xy plane in the xz plane where the red line lies...I don't know what kind of example you need

Comment: This is actually a good question.  AFAIK, it's not possible in gnuplot without manually specifying a grid yourself with headless arrows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly this is currently not supported by the `grid` command, a feature request should probably be posted.

Anyway, as suggested by *mgilson* you can manually add the grid-lines with for-loops and the `set arrow` command. For example adding the following two lines:

```
set for [x = -10:10:2] arrow from x/10.0, 0, 0 to x/10.0, 0, 100 nohead lt 0
set for [z = 0:100:10] arrow from     -1, 0, z to      1, 0,   z nohead lt 0
```

Results in:

[image: Plot that includes XZ grid]

You may want to rotate the plot with `set view`. The divide-by-ten is there because floating-point increment doesn't seem to work.

Or if you wanted the grids to be on the back of the box, do something like this:

```
set for [x = -10:10:2] arrow from x/10.0, 100, 0 to x/10.0, 100, 100 nohead lt 0
set for [z = 0:100:10] arrow from     -1, 100, z to      1, 100,   z nohead lt 0

set for [y = 0:100:10] arrow from     -1,   y, 0 to -1,   y, 100 nohead lt 0
set for [z = 0:100:10] arrow from     -1,   0, z to -1, 100,   z nohead lt 0
```

Which results in:

[image: Plot that includes grid at the back of the two walls of the plot]

### A style note

You can replace:

```
set xtics axis
set ytics axis
set ztics axis

set xzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
set yzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
set zzeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
```

with the equivalent:

```
set tics axis
set zeroaxis lt 1 lw 2 lc rgb "black"
```

Answer (score 5):

This works in gnuplot 4.6:

```
set grid ztics
```

Have a look at this article: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node188.html

And for a complicated example: http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/bargraphs.html

Comment: Nice. Although, this seems to have some issues when the tics are on the axis, the grid is drawn inside the box. For example, try plotting the OPs script with `set grid ztics`.